# Change color and icon menu using Nativescript

Tags: angular, menu, nativescript

I have this menu in all component:

```
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal" class="foot" backgroundColor="#eae8e8" padding = "10 5 10 5" >
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/home']" width="25%" textAlignment="center">
            <Image src="~/assets/images/home.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
            <Label text="Home">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/settings']" width="25%" textAlignment="center">
            <Image src="~/assets/images/settings.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
            <Label text="Setting">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/photos']" width="25%" textAlignment="center">
            <Image src="~/assets/images/photos.png" width="30" height="20" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
            <Label text="Photos">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/gallery']" width="25%" textAlignment="center">
            <Image src="~/assets/images/gallery.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
            <Label text="Gallery">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

I want, when I click a menu change color in text, color image like in menu PlayGround
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04V5n.png)

[Demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HzSteg)

Comment: can you please create nativescript playground demo?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HzSteg

Comment: do you want to change the colour of a whole label's  text or just part of it?

Comment: I want to change color only label's text and image that I click.

Comment: just get the element via a viewchild and apply a colour style

Comment: Can you try something please in my demo?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I tried something like this https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=88BQ7R

Comment: @abiiba that's just changing text color but not of image.